# External swf loading while compiling but not after exporting

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, external

I am using as1/2 script to load a external swf file

```
loadMovieNum("marioStrtfight.swf", 0);

keylistener = new Object();
keylistener.onKeyDown = function ()
{
    if (Key.getCode() == 49)
    {
        _level0.LP_P1.reset();
        _level0.element_mc.life_power.LP_P1.power_now = 300;
        _level0.P1_role.life = 300;
    }
};
Key.addListener(keylistener);
```

While testing the file is loading perfectly but after exporting its not loading.
When i right click on the screen i am getting popup as 'Flash movie not loaded'

any help

Answer (score 1):

You should not use loadMovieNum.

You should create a MovieClip inside which you will load your external swf.
The best way to load your external swf is MovieClipLoader.

```
var mclListener:Object = new Object();
mclListener.onLoadInit = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this, onLoadInitEvt);

var mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
mcl.addListener(mclListener);
mcl.loadClip("marioStrtfight.swf", the_name_of_the_clip_you_created);

function onLoadInitEvt():Void {
  trace("load ready");
}
```

You should check that the external swf is exactly in the same folder configuration as when you're testing in Flash.

Comment: Are they exported in the same Flash version ?

Comment: here is the file location http://gameslist.com/play/Mario-Street-Fight-Game Any help